# How remove item by ID from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Greeting. Do I need 
Example:

```
items: [{id:1 , name: test} , {id: 2 , name: test2} , {id:3 , name: test3}];
```

I want to delete example item where id 3?

Comment: you have to get the Array first and after do .filter to delete item

Comment: so first i go getItem filter and go back without it id???

Answer (score 2):

First, fetch the array from local storage.

```
const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));
```

Then, delete the item from the array.

```
const filtered = items.filter(item => item.id !== 3);
```

Last, put the array back in local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(filtered));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `getItem`, you get back a string. Assuming what you've stored it valid JSON, you can convert it to an actual object by doing `JSON.parse(string)`.

Once you have the object, you can do:

```
const newData = result.filter(x => x.id !== 3);
```

Now you can save this result back to localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can consider it as remove element on array, first you need find index of element has id = 3. Let's try

```
let items = [{id:1 , name: test} , {id: 2 , name: test2} , {id:3 , name: test3}];
let index = items.findIndex(element => element.id === 3)

items = items.splice(index, 1)
```

After you changed items, you can update localStore with new data.