# How to delete a specific item from localstorage in react redux

Tags: javascript, react-redux, local-storage

How can I remove a specific item (by id) from localstorage using react (redux - persist)? handleSubmit is working fine, but handleDelete, is not. I have this:

```
 handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.addWeather(this.state.weatherCity);
    this.setState({ weatherCity: "" });
  };

handleDelete = (event, id) => {
    this.props.deleteWeather(this.state.weatherCity);
    this.setState({ weatherCity: "" });
  }

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      allWeather: state.allWeather
    });
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
      bindActionCreators(WeatherActions, dispatch);
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WeatherList);
```

And button in form to call handleDelete:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleDelete}><button type="submit" id="add" onClick={this.handleDelete}>Remove City</button></form>
```

My localstorage:

```
allWeather: "[{\"id\":0.5927975642362653,\"city\":\"Toronto\"},{\"id\":0.8124764603718682,\"city\":\"Fortaleza\"},{\"id\":0.9699736666575081,\"city\":\"Porto\"},{\"id\":0.852871998478355,\"city\":\"Tokio\"},{\"id\":0.8854642571682461,\"city\":\"New York\"}]"
```

My reducer:

```
export default function allWeather(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_WEATHER":
      return [...state, { id: Math.random(), city: action.payload.city }];
    case "DELETE_ITEM":
      return [...state, state.weatherCity.filter((event, id) => id !== action.payload.id)];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And actions:

```
export const deleteWeather = id => ({
  type: "DELETE_ITEM",
  payload: { id }
});
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60254872/how-remove-item-by-id-from-localstorage perhaps that will help you

Comment: if you want to delete an item in the redux store (it doesn't matter it's configured to save it in localStorage using redux-persist) you need to dispatch an action or that. But the given code is just updating the local component state.

Comment: I tried this (the changes are above), but still not working. What am I doing wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using the spread operator, which copies the content of the current state first. Then you are adding the items that were returned from the filter method. So you aren't deleting but adding. To delete from an array use the filter method only, without the spread operator like that:

`return  state.filter( (city) => city.id !== action.payload.id )`

Also the state is an array, not an object, so this is invalid `state.weatherCity`.